# Using previous rows data to calculate values for multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, iteration, pandas-groupby

I have the following df (groupby product, type and period):

```
+---------+----------+--------+-----------------+---------+---------+
| product |   type   | period | currentquantity | damage1 | damage2 |
+---------+----------+--------+-----------------+---------+---------+
| A       | shopping |      1 |              20 |    0.15 |    0.05 |
| A       | shopping |      2 |              20 |    0.15 |    0.05 |
| A       | shopping |      3 |              20 |    0.15 |    0.05 |
| A       | shopping |      4 |              20 |    0.15 |    0.05 |
| A       | shopping |      5 |              20 |    0.15 |    0.05 |
| B       | shopping |      1 |               4 |    0.15 |    0.05 |
| B       | shopping |      2 |               4 |    0.15 |    0.05 |
| B       | shopping |      3 |               4 |    0.15 |    0.05 |
| B       | shopping |      4 |               4 |    0.15 |    0.05 |
| B       | shopping |      5 |               4 |    0.15 |    0.05 |
+---------+----------+--------+-----------------+---------+---------+
```

Require:

```
+---------+----------+--------+-----------------+---------+---------+----------------+----------------+--------------+
| product |   type   | period | currentquantity | damage1 | damage2 | damage1_impact | damage2_impact | new_quantity |
+---------+----------+--------+-----------------+---------+---------+----------------+----------------+--------------+
| A       | shopping |      1 |              20 |    0.15 |    0.05 |              3 |              1 |           16 |
| A       | shopping |      2 |              20 |    0.15 |    0.05 |            2.4 |            0.8 |         12.8 |
| A       | shopping |      3 |              20 |    0.15 |    0.05 |            1.9 |            0.6 |         10.2 |
| A       | shopping |      4 |              20 |    0.15 |    0.05 |            1.5 |            0.5 |          8.2 |
| A       | shopping |      5 |              20 |    0.15 |    0.05 |            1.2 |            0.4 |          6.6 |
| B       | shopping |      1 |               4 |    0.15 |    0.05 |            0.6 |            0.2 |          3.2 |
| B       | shopping |      2 |               4 |    0.15 |    0.05 |            0.5 |            0.2 |          2.6 |
| B       | shopping |      3 |               4 |    0.15 |    0.05 |            0.4 |            0.1 |          2.0 |
| B       | shopping |      4 |               4 |    0.15 |    0.05 |            0.3 |            0.1 |          1.6 |
| B       | shopping |      5 |               4 |    0.15 |    0.05 |            0.2 |            0.1 |          1.3 |
+---------+----------+--------+-----------------+---------+---------+----------------+----------------+--------------+
```

Three output columns (groupby product, type, period): damage1_impact, damage2_impact, new_quantity.

For df.period==1 only, use the same row values but all other periods use the previous row values for that df.product and df.type. That is,

```
df.damage1_impact (only for period ==1)  = df.currentquantity * df.damage1  (20*.15 = 3)

df.damage2_impact (only for period ==1)  = df.currentquantity * df.damage1  (20*.05 = 1)

df.new_quantity (only for period ==1)    = df.currentquantity - (df.damage1_impact+df.damage2_impact)= 20 - (3+1)=16
```

For df.period 2 and greater:

```
df.damage1_impact = df.damage1 * df.new_quantity (from the pervious Period) = .15 * 16 = 2.4

df.damage2_impact = df.damage2 * df.new_quantity (from the pervious Period) = .05 * 16 = 0.8

df.new_quantity = df.new_quantity (from the pervious period) - (df.damage1_impact+df.damage2_impact)= 16 - (2.4 + 0.8) = 12.8
```

(column df.currentquantity is used only in df.period==1 and for all other periods, it's the previous row values of df.newquantity)

Would it be possible to do this calculation without any loops?

Answer (score 1):

Iterrows based solution. Not very elegant, but should do the job as per your requirement.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('damage.csv')
df.loc[df['period'] == 1, 'Impact_Damage1'] = df.current_quantity * df.damage1/100
for i, row in df.iterrows():
   dp=df.loc[i, 'period'] - 1
   if dp > 0:
     df1 = df[df['period'] == dp]
     prd = df.loc[i, 'product']
     df.at[i, 'Impact_Damage1'] = df1.loc[df1['product'] == prd, 'current_quantity'] * df1.loc[df1['product'] == prd, 'damage1']/100
print(df)
```

Will be interesting to see a more compact and elegant solution instead of row by row operation.

Comment: thanks for this. I have sorted the data now in the question, which makes it a bit easier I believe